# Animating processbar in ProgressView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to animate the progress bar in the SwiftUI progress view. I found something that can help for this but in UIProgressView however I trying to accomplish this with SwiftUI. Current approach:

```
ProgressView(value: 0.25).animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3))
```

The problem with this is the whole view is being animated. I want only the progress bar animated.

Comment: it is not possible with just adding animation modifier, because Apple already added an animation by default, and that is why your animation does not take place! we should make and update the value in timer and plug that values to slider to making illusion of the animation you want, do you need this way, then I can help.

Comment: Yes please. if you know how to do that it would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this

```
@State private var counter = 0.0

var body: some View {
    ProgressView(value: counter, total: 100.0)
        .onAppear {
            self.runCounter(counter: self.$counter, start: 0.0, end: 50.0, speed: 0.05)
        }
}

func runCounter(counter: Binding<Double>, start: Double, end: Double, speed: Double) {
    counter.wrappedValue = start

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: speed, repeats: true) { timer in
        counter.wrappedValue += 1.0
        if counter.wrappedValue == end {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom animation, it is not the final version or even final code but it would solve your issue,

---

[image]

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var value: CGFloat = 0.5
    @State private var valueAnimation: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var qualityOfAnimation: Quality = .excellent
    @State private var duration: Double = 5.0

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 30.0) {
            
            Text(String(describing: qualityOfAnimation) + " Quality").bold()

            ProgressView(value: valueAnimation)
                .customAnimation(value: value, valueAnimation: $valueAnimation, duration: duration, qualityOfAnimation: qualityOfAnimation)

            Button("update to 1.0") { value = 1.0 }
            
            Button("update to 0.0") { value = 0.0 }
            
            Button("update to slow Quality") { qualityOfAnimation = .slow }
            
            Button("update to excellent Quality") { qualityOfAnimation = .excellent }
            
            HStack { Text("Duration:").bold().fixedSize(); Slider(value: $duration,in: 0.0...10.0); Text(duration.rounded + " sec").bold().frame(width: 80).fixedSize() }
  
        }
        .padding()

    }

}



struct CustomAnimationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    var value: CGFloat
    @Binding var valueAnimation: CGFloat
    var duration: Double
    var qualityOfAnimation: Quality
    
    init(value: CGFloat, valueAnimation: Binding<CGFloat>, duration: Double, qualityOfAnimation: Quality) {
        
        self.value = value
        self._valueAnimation = valueAnimation
        self.duration = duration
        self.qualityOfAnimation = qualityOfAnimation
        
    }
    
    

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        return content
            .onAppear() { valueAnimation = value }
            .onChange(of: value) { [value] newValue in

                let millisecondsDuration: Int = Int(duration * 1000)
                let tik: Int = qualityOfAnimation.rawValue
                let step: CGFloat = (newValue - value)/CGFloat(millisecondsDuration/tik)
                valueAnimationFunction(tik: tik, step: step, value: newValue, increasing: step > 0.0 ? true : false)

            }

    }
    
    func valueAnimationFunction(tik: Int, step: CGFloat, value: CGFloat, increasing: Bool) {

        if increasing {
            
            if valueAnimation + step < value {
                
                valueAnimation += step
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(tik)) {
                    
                    valueAnimationFunction(tik: tik, step: step, value: value, increasing: increasing)
                    
                }
                
            }
            else {
                valueAnimation = value
                
            }
            
        }
        else {

            if valueAnimation + step > value {
                
                valueAnimation += step
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(tik)) {
                    
                    valueAnimationFunction(tik: tik, step: step, value: value, increasing: increasing)
                    
                }
                
            }
            else {
                valueAnimation = value
                
            }
 
        }

    }

}


extension View {

    func customAnimation(value: CGFloat, valueAnimation: Binding<CGFloat>, duration: Double, qualityOfAnimation: Quality = Quality.excellent) -> some View {

        return self.modifier(CustomAnimationViewModifier(value: value, valueAnimation: valueAnimation, duration: duration, qualityOfAnimation: qualityOfAnimation))

    }
 
}


enum Quality: Int, CustomStringConvertible {

    case excellent = 1, high = 10, basic = 100, slow = 1000

    var description: String {

        switch self {
        case .excellent: return "excellent"
        case .high: return "high"
        case .basic: return "basic"
        case .slow: return "slow"

        }
 
    }

}

extension Double { var rounded: String { get { return String(Double(self*100.0).rounded()/100.0) } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate only the progress bar I have used `animation(_ animation:value:)` like this:

```swift
ProgressView(value: Double(currentQuestionIndex + 1), total: Double(questions.count)).animation(.easeIn(duration: 3), value: currentQuestionIndex)
```

What I discovered is that when we use `animation(_ animation:value:)` we can add a variable and when that variable is changed the animation happens. So for this whenever the variable (currentQuestionIndex) changes the animation happens which looks like this at the end:

https://i.imgur.com/1OuCdIN.gif